# CMake: setting the TARGET_FILE generator expression of a custom target

Tags: cmake

I have a custom target. How do I set it's `TARGET_FILE` generator expression.

```
add_custom_target(my_target)
...
# set TARGET_FILE
...
# Use $<TARGET_FILE:my_target>
```

I tried to set the `LOCATION` target property hoping that then the `TARGET_FILE` generator expression would point to it, but that is not the case.

Comment: Expression `TARGET_FILE` is constructed as `{OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/{PREFIX}{OUTPUT_NAME}{SUFFIX}` where `{XXX}` denotes the value of the target property `XXX`. You could try to set all 4 properties for `my_target` (e.g. using [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) command).

Comment: `add_custom_target` doesn't allow you to specify an output (in contrast to `add_custom_command`). We're probably dealing with an XY problem here. It would be preferrable to get a description of the problem you're trying to solve here. I'm not even sure `add_custom_target` creates a cmake target you can access target properties for; At least it doesn't have a non-internal type listed in the documentation of [the `TYPE` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/TYPE.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a custom target. How do I set it's TARGET_FILE generator expression.

It is not possible, from [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html):

> The target has no output file

ergo it has no `TARGET_FILE` generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer pointed out, this cannot be done with `add_custom_target`, but if what you want is a custom target which has the `TARGET_FILE` property, then that is possible. The following technique is useful if you have a non-C++ executable which is built via some other mechanism (e.g. perhaps it is just a shell script or maybe it's a self-extracting package, etc).

`dummy-main.cc`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# This is the custom command where you generate the custom binary. Maybe it's
# a special compiler for a dynamic language, or maybe you're just creating
# an executable zipfile for python.
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my-custom-binary.real
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/empty.cc
  COMMAND make-my-custom-binary
    -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my-custom-binary.real
  # There is no way to add a file-level dependency between some
  # `add_executable` and this generated file, so we have to generate a
  # stub .cc file just so we can depend on it in `add_executable`
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/empty.cc
)

# In cmake, a c++ binary is the only first class citizen. Here, we have a
# custom binary which is generated in some other way and we want cmake to
# treat it like a C++ binary in so much as the target is a name in the global
# namespace of targets and can be used in generator expressions and has
# properties and things. So, first we create a dummy executable:
add_executable(
  my-custom-binary
  dummy-main.cc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/empty.cc
)

# Then, in the POST_BUILD commands, we delete the executable created by the
# C++ compiler, and replace it with the executable we constructed through
# some other means. 
add_custom_command(
  TARGET my-custom-binary
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND rm $<TARGET_FILE:my-custom-binary>
  COMMAND cp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my-custom-binary.real
          $<TARGET_FILE:my-custom-binary>
)
```

Some other `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# Since your custom binary appears to cmake indistinguishable from a C++
# binary, we can use it in the same ways. If our custom binary were a
# code generator, for example, we might do something like this somewhere
# else in our build system
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.h
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cc
  DEPENDS foo.in my-custom-binary
  COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:my-custom-binary>
      -i ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.in
      -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} 
)
```

NOTE: I've verified this technique in a build system, but not this exact code. I may have made typos or other transcription/redaction errors.